# React : How can i prevent Maximum update depth exceeded from a function beign called in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this error :

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls
> setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a
> dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

I have this state :

```
const [arrayOfDocuments, setArrayOfDocuments] = useState([]);
```

which store objects of type document

Function which add the docs to the state :

```
  const pushToArrayOfDocuments = (obj) => {
    if (obj.filename && obj.file && obj.expiredate && obj.doctype) {
      setArrayOfDocuments((oldArr) => {
        const arr = oldArr.slice();
        const index = arr.map((e) => e.filename).indexOf(obj.filename);

        if (index !== -1) {
          arr[index] = obj;
        } else {
          arr.push(obj);
        }

        return arr;
      });
    }
  };
```

Now this function is beign passed to the sub components :

like this :

```
<OperatorDocument
  key={`Visura camerale${count}`}
  title="Visura camerale"
  setDocument={pushToArrayOfDocuments}
  description=" in dolor."
  document={getObjectByName('Visura camerale')}
  filedocname="Visura camerale"
 />
```

Now inside the subcomponent i have this state :

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(document);
```

Now if this state changes i call   setDocument inside useEffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setDocument(file);
  }, [file, setDocument]);
```

and now i get the error.
Any idea on how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

The error already told you the problem because setState is in the array dependency the component updates Everytime.

Try this
Delete the setDocument and leave just file in the dependency array that way it updates only when the file changes

Like this [file]

Comment: But eslint says to add it , what if i wrap the function in useCallback?